# Ubuntu Software Center does not launch, error when refreshing cache

Tags: software-center

When I click on the Ubuntu software icon on the dock, pointer turns to spinning circle for a while but the application does not launch. I tried to run below commands but I am getting an error while refreshing cache. Please help.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list

sudo software-properties-gtk
```

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: 20.04.2 LTS 64-bit.

Comment: That `sudo rm` command was most unwise. You just made things harder than they needed to be. To fix that particular mistake, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories

Comment: I followed the steps mentioned there but I am still having the same error.